# iOS NSUserDefaults remove object for key but do not delete the key

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults

If we set nil for a key in user defaults, it deletes the key as well.What if we want to delete the object but keep the key intact. How to do that. Any help will be appreciable.
Thanks

Comment: You are saving array or dictionary or custom object ?

Comment: Register a default value for that key in `NSUserDefaults` and then revert to that default value.

Comment: What's wrong with deleting the key and dealing with it during the read?

Answer (score 0):

NSUserDefaults doesn't support NSNull. So you'd have to find any value that you wish to represent "no data" and set that. For example an empty string, an empty array, or an empty dictionary. You can then distinguish between a result of nil (default was never set), your marker value (indicating that the value was set by you but is supposed to mean "nothing"), or any ordinary value.

Comment: It's still not clear why you can't just delete it and manage that during a read...

Answer (score -1):

Try to set `[NSNull null]` for that key.

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSNull null] forKey:@"key"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Comment: This will crash, because NSNull is not supported by NSUserDefaults.